# HTML table from C# list

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net-mvc, html-table

I'm new to MVC and HTML coding in general.

I have a SQL table [Schedule] with columns, Date, ActivityID, UserID that is full of data.

I have a MVC project set up, with a Schedule Model set up.

In my Controller:

```
public List<Schedule> ScheduleList { get; set; }
//...

//Fill the Schedule list with the data in the database.
ScheduleList = context.Schedule.ToList();
```

In my HTML View I want to create a table that populates each Activity along the top and each Date down the left side / first column. Then each cell in the table have each user that has both the data and the AcitviyID.

Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Try the [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add a few other things to your model. The list of Activities to populate the column headers, and the list of dates for the row headers. Honestly, all you'd need is the name and ID of each Activity for the headers.

So you'd add another model like this:

```
public class ActivityHeader {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So then your Model would need to also have (I'll leave you to figure out how to populate them):
    public List Headers { get; set; }
    public List Dates { get; set; }

Then on your Razor page, you'll lay out the table like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var header in Model.Headers) {
                <th data-id="@header.Id">@header.Name</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var date in Model.Dates) {
            <tr>
                <td>@date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                // Figure out how to match the date and Activity to the list of Schedules.
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```